# Why I'm forced to use raw socket to write ebpf programs with BCC?

Tags: python, sockets, ebpf, bcc-bpf

**GOAL:** write an eBPF packet filter program that doesn't require high privileges.

**PROBLEM:** from what I understood I have to use `attach_raw_socket` function to attach my filter to an interface. This functions invokes `bpf_open_raw_sock` libbpf function which open a raw_socket that requires high privileges (https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/10dae9eac33287c1df9e6645933b608c2d2c5640/src/cc/libbpf.c#L674-L678).

**QUESTION:** Is there a way to attach an ebpf filter to another socket type, like SOCK_DGRAM (with cBPF is possible)?.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from bcc import BPF
import socket
import os

# backend part
# ebpf program written using restricted C
c_ebpf = """
#include <uapi/linux/if_ether.h>
#include <uapi/linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/in.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
int icmp_filter(struct __sk_buff *skb){
    int proto = load_byte(skb, ETH_HLEN + offsetof(struct iphdr, protocol)); 
if(proto == IPPROTO_ICMP && skb->pkt_type == PACKET_OUTGOING){
  return -1;
} else { return 0; }
}
"""

# loader
bpf = BPF(text=c_ebpf)
ffilter = bpf.load_func("icmp_filter", BPF.SOCKET_FILTER)
BPF.attach_raw_socket(ffilter, "enp0s3")

# frontend part
socketfd = ffilter.sock

sockobj = socket.fromfd(socketfd, socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
sockobj.setblocking(True)

while 1:
    pkt_str = os.read(socketfd, 2048)
    pkt_bytearray = bytearray(pkt_str)
    ip_protocol = pkt_bytearray[23]
    print ("%s" % hex(ip_protocol))
```

Comment: I suppose you could *in theory* attach a BPF filter to a `SOCK_DGRAM` (UDP) socket, but there's not really much point so I doubt the kernel supports it.

Comment: Why there is not much point?

Comment: What's you use-case for doing do? By the time a packet is associated with a UDP socket, its Ethernet, IP, and UDP headers have already been evaluated. The only data remaining is application data. What application wants to selectively include/exclude a high volume of its protocol data?

Comment: It's just for exercise.
Using an UDP socket I should have also the UDP headers. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Did you try some C code to attach an eBPF program with `setsockopt()`? (See `man setsockopt` and `man 7 socket`).

Comment: really I'd try but still I can't understand how to do It. 
With cBPF is straightforward, write the filter -> create the socket -> attach the filter.
With eBPF I've seen you need to write 2 files. One which is  the eBPF program and one which is the user-space frontend. But  you need to create a new section and compile with clang/llvm and then load the bytecode (maybe). I just have a basic idea of the workflow.

Comment: That's it, but it's not as hard as it seems :). The ELF section thing is optional, it will default to `.text` section if you don't set one and you can pass it to `ip link` or `tc filter` or `bpftool`. For attaching an eBPF program to a socket, 1) write the program, 2) compile it (one call to `clang`), 3) load it (e.g. `bpftool prog load`, or use libbpf in your user app - no need to do the extraction from ELF sections manually), 4) attach it to your socket.

I don't know if it's possible to attach programs to `SOCK_DGRAM` with bcc, but indeed I'm not sure many folks are interested in that.

Comment: Thank you very much. So before to get my hands dirty and getting crazy:
1) I guess I can reuse the C code above
2) clang -O2 -emit-llvm -c bpf.c -o - | llc -march=bpf -filetype=obj
           -o bpf.o  
3) Has bpftool prog load the same effect of  if (bpf_prog_load(filename, BPF_PROG_TYPE_SOCKET_FILTER,
     &obj, &prog_fd))
  return 1;
where filename is the path of my eBPF compiled with clang? Does load mean that the program is loaded in the kernel-space right?
4) setsockopt(... , SO_ATTACH_BPF, ...);
Sorry if I bother you ahha. You're great