# Why ebpf program inside samples/bpf doesn't work?

Tags: c, kernel, bpf, ebpf

**GOAL:** write a new `ebpf` example within `samples/bpf` directory in the kernel source tree of 4.18.0, compile and execute it.

**PROBLEM:** after compiling it when I run `sudo ./mine` it just terminates.

**mine_kern.c**

```
#include <uapi/linux/bpf.h>
#include <uapi/linux/if_ether.h>
#include <uapi/linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/in.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include "bpf_helpers.h" 

int icmp_filter(struct __sk_buff *skb){

        int proto = load_byte(skb, ETH_HLEN + offsetof(struct iphdr, protocol));
        if(proto == IPPROTO_ICMP && skb->pkt_type == PACKET_OUTGOING){
           return -1;
        } else {
           return 0;
        }
}

char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
```

**mine_user.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <bpf/bpf.h>
#include "bpf_load.h"
#include "sock_example.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>    

int main(int ac, char **argv)
{
    char filename[256];
    FILE *f;
    int i, sock;

    snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "%s_kern.o", argv[0]);

    if (load_bpf_file(filename)) {
        printf("%s", bpf_log_buf);
        return 1;
    }   

    sock = open_raw_sock("lo");

    assert(setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ATTACH_BPF, prog_fd,
              sizeof(prog_fd[0])) == 0);

    f = popen("ping -c5 localhost", "r");
    (void) f;

    char buf[65535];

    for(i=0; i<20; i++){
           int res = recvfrom(sock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, NULL, 0);
           printf("res=%d\n", res);
     } 

     return 0;
}
```

I've also modified the `Makefile` inside `samples/bpf` adding `mine_user.c` and `mine_kern.c` where required.
**QUESTIONS:** what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Have you tried to *debug* your user-space program?

Comment: I've tried to put some printf and it enters in the first if so it terminates because of the return 1; statement. Also If printf(%s, bpf_log_buf) doesn't print anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way `load_bpf_file()` loads the function, you need to put your BPF program function in a separate ELF section. For example, I could load the program with:

```c
SEC("socket")
int icmp_filter(struct __sk_buff *skb){
        ...
}
```

After that, I see a succession of `res=-1` when running the program. This is because your socket is set as non-blocking by `open_raw_sock()`, from `sock_example.h`:

```c
sock = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW|SOCK_NONBLOCK|SOCK_CLOEXEC, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
```

So when there is no packet to receive, `recvfrom()` simply returns with `-1` (and sets `errno` to `-EGAIN` -- you should consider printing `strerror(errno)` by the way) instead of waiting for a packet. So you may want to change that too.

Comment: Thanks again!. 1) Does SEC() requires specific names? Because I've tried to use a random name like SEC("mine") and it didn't work (mine_user mine_kern are the name of the files). Then I've tried one that I've seen in another example (e.g. SEC("socket1") and it worked fine
2) why the socket is opened in a non blocking way? could I open up a socket by myself without SOCK_NONBLOCK or is discouraged?

Comment: tools/lib/bpf/libbpf.c I think section_names[] answers my first question.

Comment: You didn't use libbpf in your case. You used `bpf_load.c`, and it requires a specific _prefix_, in your case: `socket`. See [the code](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/samples/bpf/bpf_load.c?h=v5.2#n627). For 2) that's simply the way that sample was coded, again see the code/[commit log](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/samples/bpf/bpf_load.c?id=03f4723ed7a52bd31da26eefe2cdde563ea0f468): The user app doesn't read the socket, just BPF maps. I don't see why opening a classic blocking socket should be discouraged.

Comment: ah I thought I was using libbpf because at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/samples/bpf  the first sentence states "The examples use libbpf from tools/lib/bpf." 
So load_bpf_file is from bpf_load.c and bpf_prog_load from libbpf. Now I' m more confused than before . When should I use one and when the other?

Comment: Most content of `bpf_load.c` predates libbpf. This lead to a situation where BPF programs use a variety of loaders. Today, most have moved to libbpf, and this should be the reference for handling BPF object files and programs. Some samples still use `bpf_load.c` (and that file might even include some stuff from libbpf itself, I don't remember). Feel free to experiment with this loader, but if you build a serious project, definitely go for libbpf (and build your programs out of the kernel tree, it may make your life easier).

Comment: Till now the only way I could build a program out of the kernel tree was using BCC. I need to understand well which are all the ways to write, compile and execute an eBPF program:
1) Inside kernel tree I can load it using bpf_load or libbpf or bpftool. CONS: too much dependencies on the kernel tree. 
2) Outside kernel tree: BCC, backend C, fontend python  
3) Outside kernel tree: write in C (which headers do I need?), compile with clang, load with tools/library. But how can I use libbpf and bpftool outside of the kernel tree if they are build inside?

Comment: Indeed I've seen there is a bpf syscall but I've never seen an example using it.

Comment: You don't need to use the syscall yourself, libbpf handles that for you. Apart from headers/includes, 3) is the same as 1). You can get it libbpf of the tree, there's [a GitHub mirror](https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf) you can download, install and use as any other C library. Did you look at the examples I provided? [bpf-samples](https://github.com/Netronome/bpf-samples/) use libbpf out of the tree to build the programs (the libbpf GitHub repo is added as a Git submodule). And other than for building it, `bpftool` works with any BPF stuff, not just the samples in the kernel.

Comment: Ok so I can get the libbpf,  write my backend using bpf functions which already comes with my kernel, then include the libbpf.h header and link the .so  to my frontend.  I've seen them but they are quite complicated for me :(. I'm trying the simplest things I can and still I'm struggling. 
OT: I was reading bpf man and "In the current implementation, all bpf() commands require the caller to have the CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability." So it means that every ebpf program needs to be run with sudo. Is this always true?

Comment: No, the `bpf()` man page is completely out-of-date. Regarding permissions, you need this capability for most commands and program types, but [not for socket filters](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/bpf/syscall.c?h=v5.2#n1621) or some of the cgroup stuff.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197345/discussion-between-maicake-and-qeole).